# How to compare row values with in a same group (DataFrame)?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a DataFrame like this:

```
location  | date     | sum   |
----------+----------+-------+
USA       | 1-2-2001 | 35    |
          | 1-1-2001 | 32    |
China     | 1-2-2001 | 40    |
          | 1-1-2001 | 31    |
```

I would like to create a new column deciding whether the sum value of a day is greater than that of the previous day by 20% within a country. The outcome should be like:

```
location  | date     | sum   |compare|
----------+----------+-------+-------+
USA       | 1-2-2001 | 35    | FALSE |
          | 1-1-2001 | 32    | FALSE |
China     | 1-2-2001 | 40    | TRUE  |
          | 1-1-2001 | 31    | FALSE |
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you need `Series.pct_change`?

Comment: `groupby().pct_change()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer:

```
data = {'location': ['USA', 'USA', 'China', 'China'],
        'date': ['1-2-2001', '1-1-2001', '1-2-2001', '1-1-2001'],
        'sum': [35, 32, 40, 31]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['sum2'] = df.groupby('location')['sum'].shift(-1)
def cond1(x):
    if x['sum'] > (x['sum2']*.2 + x['sum2']):
        return True
    else:
        return False

df['compare'] = df.apply(cond1, axis=1)
```